# BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor ignores Encrypted properties

Tags: java, spring, encryption, jasypt

I've registered a Spring Post Processor to register some beans based on application properties.
Also I would like to add support for encrypted properties.

I use **spring** and **jasypt spring boot**

Here are my configurations:

application.yml:

```
rest:
  jwt-client:
    location:
      base-url: loc_URL
      invoke-timeout:
        connection: 5000
        read: 500
      jwt-config:
        token: ENC(gRbmO8Gv2Yb3vUf27nykDPd5/wjVdj+r5REr5HcIh4k=)
```

Post Processor class:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DynamicClientBeanConfiguration implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor {

    private static final String BEAN_POSTFIX = "-api-client-config";
    private final Environment environment;

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(@NonNull BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) {
        Binder.get(environment)
                .bind("rest.jwt-client", Bindable.mapOf(String.class, JwtClientConfig.class))
                .orElse(new LinkedHashMap<>())
                .forEach((key, value) -> {
                    GenericBeanDefinition bd = new GenericBeanDefinition();
                    bd.setBeanClass(JwtClientConfig.class);
                    bd.setInstanceSupplier(() -> value);
                    bd.addQualifier(new AutowireCandidateQualifier(key + BEAN_POSTFIX));
                    registry.registerBeanDefinition(key + BEAN_POSTFIX, bd);
                    log.debug("Registered JwtClientConfig bean with @Qualifier(\"{}\")", key + BEAN_POSTFIX);
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(@NonNull ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
        // Nothing to override
    }
}
```

Custom Configuration Properties class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ConfigurationProperties
public class JwtClientConfig {
    private String baseUrl;
    private InvokeTimeout invokeTimeout;
    private JwtConfig jwtConfig;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    public static class InvokeTimeout {
        private int connection;
        private int read;
    }

    @Getter
    @Setter
    public static class JwtConfig {
        private String token;
    }
}
```

However when the following part of code in the post processor executed it binds raw data from properties like ENC(...) but not decrypted as I expect:

```
Binder.get(environment)
      .bind("rest.jwt-client", Bindable.mapOf(String.class, JwtClientConfig.class))
      .orElse(new LinkedHashMap<>())
```

It it possible to bind already decrypted properties in Post Processor?

Comment: Not really as the encryption is also done by a post processor, it actually post processes the environment and wraps the property sources. So you have kind of a chicken/egg problem. But why this code in the firs tplace? The `@ConfigurationProperties` are already supported out-of-the-box so why the post processor in the first place?

Comment: I'm trying to create bunch of JwtClientConfig beans dynamically, so I dont need any explicitly declared @ConfigurationProperties beans. Just trying to code less